# Limitations to + operator for arrays

Tags: php

The following code is producing an `Unsupported operator types` error:

```
$data = $modelData + array_merge($data, $recordData);
```

What the issue is, though, is that `$modelData`, `$data`, and `$recordData` are all arrays. The contents can be found here: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1477154570

So I have to wonder if there are limitations to using + operator or some other underlying issue.

Edit: Exact php version: PHP 5.3.10 on Win 7 64-bit

Comment: Can you show the contents of `$modelData`, `$data` and `$recordData`? Maybe one of them is not an array?

Comment: @Nanne its in the link in my question

Comment: There is no error when running on PHP 5.3.10 on Linux. What's your PHP and OS?

Comment: PHP version is PHP 5.3.10 on Win 7 64bit

Comment: @tigrang I'm running the same OS and same PHP version as you and it works for me. Strange.

Comment: Trying `$data = $modelData + array_merge($data, $recordData);` on the arrays with your contents (from your code in the link) works perfectly for me.

Comment: @tigrang It looks like your issue is something other than the code you are concentrating on as it seems to work for everybody else. Don't you just love debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to merge 2 arrays and then do union with third one.
Looks ok to me. Please let me know if I am missing anything.
here is the tried code with your given data. 
           http://codepad.org/hA654cQE

Comment: Running the snippet Sunil provided in another script on my computer works. So it looks this is only happening in this one project. Still, no idea why. I'm going to mark this as the answer and if I figure out why I'll post back here. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a built-in language feature instead of a function. So it might be that it only accepts arrays in variable form, not as a result from functions. (Not sure though.)

### Edit

Nope. Tested this code and it worked:

```
php > $a = array('w' => 'hello');
php > $b = array('x' => 'world');              
php > $c = array('y' => '!', 'z' => 1337);
php > $d = $a + array_merge($b, $c);
php > var_dump($d);
array(4) {
  ["w"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  ["x"]=>
  string(5) "world"
  ["y"]=>
  string(1) "!"
  ["z"]=>
  int(1337)
}
```

On PHP 5.4.3 CLI. Arch Linux.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case according to my testing, in the most basic sense, the `array_merge` function returns an array and therefor is the same thing as putting the array manually.

Comment: Yea did a test here, which works; http://codepad.org/hBRJSbgk

Comment: I stand corrected. Was about to perform a test myself.